# Form Select fields that have a maximum combined selectable value

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, jquery-selectors

Hello stackoverflow guru's! This is my first post after having used the site for a fair while now. My normal realm of expertise is within PHP and MySQL so when I have free time I will start to contribute in those areas.

Now my question:

I have a form I am building for a booking system.

One of the fields is a select field to ascertain how many adults and children are being booked for. The are two separate dropdown select fields with several options.

The rules of the booking script are that a maximum of 8 people can stay with a minimum of 1 adult.

Obviously I could put a condition in the processing PHP file, but thats not very good for the user experience so we want to have it that when a number of people is selected from either dropdown, it fades out any value in the other that would take the total over 8.

The HTML would be like this:

```
<select id="adults">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<select id="children">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

What I am having significant issues with is the jQuery code I will need to fade out the irrelevant options, as it needs to work both ways ie. if they select 5 children first, then adult values 4-8 are then blanked out, or if they select 3 adults first, children values 6 and 7 would blank out.

I would post what I have tried so far with jQuery, but I now know it is completely the wrong code as I was going in the direction of using jQuery calculate.

Any ideas? (Many many thanks and appreciation in advance, I am sorry that I cant provide any more info).

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cache = {
    $adults:            $('#adults'),
    $children:          $('#children')
}
cache.$adultsOptions    = cache.$adults.find('option');
cache.$childrenOptions  = cache.$children.find('option');

cache.$adults.add(cache.$children).change(function()
{
    var $this    = $(this),
        other    = $this.is( cache.$adults ) ? '$children' : '$adults',
        max      = 8 - $this.val();

    cache[other + 'Options'].each(function()
    {
        $.prop( this, 'disabled', $.attr(this, 'value') > max );
    });
});

cache.$adults.change();​
```

**Remember to always cache your selectors!!**

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmBLw/

Comment: Hi this is great! But it doesn't take into account the values for the children are 0-7 and not 1-8 like the adults. It therefore allows you to go up to 9 for some reason in some cases and only 7 in others. I am not sure if links are allowed but here is what I mean : http://bookingtest.walesdesign.com/index.html . If you select 6 or 7 in the adults field, and then the maximum it will let you in the next, it then allows you to select 1 more than the total allowed

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. It does the same on yours. If you select 6 in the adult field, then 2 in the child field, and then go back to adult, you can now select 7 which would then total 9

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I wish I could vote up for you, but it says I need 15+ reputation. Will work on that and come back!

Comment: @KevinSmith - I hadn't realized that only one of them had a 0 value. I updated the code to account for that.

Comment: thank you very much for your time, it is much appreciated. I am in the middle of trying to improve my jQuery knowledge, and noticed you mentioned to always cache your selectors, do you mind me asking why? there is only so much you can learn from specific online tutorials...

Comment: @KevinSmith - Every time you use a jQuery selector, jQuery has to go out and query the DOM for your elements. This is among the most [expensive operations you could do in your code](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/19/speed-up-the-jquery-code-selectors-cache/) (some selectors are worse than others - with the ID selector being the most efficient - but the point still stands). Caching your selectors ensures that you only query the DOM once, which will result in much better performance ([see what happened to Twitter when they didn't](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for your adults select. The code for children should be almost identical, swap adults and children identifiers.

```
$('#adults').change(function(){
    var chosen = $('#adults option:selected').val();
    var maxOther = 8 - chosen;
    for(var i = 0; i<=maxOther; i++){
        $('#children option[value="' + i + '"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    for(var i = maxOther+1; i <= 8; i++){
        $('#children option[value="' + i + '"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  maxTotal = 8;
  $('#adults').change(function () {
     var numChildren = $('#children option:selected').val();
     var maxChildren = maxTotal - numChildren + 1;
     $('#children option').each(function () {
       $(this).attr("disabled","");
     }
     for(var i = maxChildren; i <= maxTotal; i++){
       $('#children option[value="' + i + '"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
     }
  });
  $('#children').change(function () {
     var numAdults = $('#adults option:selected').val();
     var maxAdults = maxTotal - numAdults + 1;
     $('#adults option').each(function () {
       $(this).attr("disabled","");
     }
     for(var i = maxAdults; i <= maxTotal; i++){
       $('#adults option[value="' + i + '"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
     }
  });
});
```